# Remove Start Menu

Tags: lubuntu

I am customizing the Lubuntu 13.04 live usb installation. How can I remove the Start Menu on the Desktop (the main menu on the left-bottom corner of the Desktop). I want to add another menu of my choice instead. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok To do this you need to right click on the start menu. Then select Remove menu from panel. And The  start menu should no longer be there. See this documentation page for editing the files for the menu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/EditingTheMenu.